# CSS z-index causes part of tags to show through notifications on webmasters, web applications, gaming, gamedev, and their meta sites

Tags: bug, tags, design, popups

When you vote 35 times in a day and you only have five votes left, you start getting a warning popup that you are almost at your limit.  When this warning appears in the same place as the tags, part of the tags shows through it.

> [image]

This screen shot was taken on webmasters.

This is also a problem on Web Applications: [CSS bleed-thru on tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/css-bleed-thru-on-tags):

> [image: web applications]

and [Tags element overlaps notification](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/tags-element-overlaps-notification):

> [image: web applications]

This also happens on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245696/tag-appearance-bug).  Here is a [video of it happening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IO1BHb2ssE).

It is also happening on the meta sites associated with the sites that have the problem.   For example, here is web apps meta site:

[image: web apps meta bleed through]

This a minor annoyance that has been around for at least a couple years.

Comment: That would be specific to webmasters (and perhaps some other sites that styled the tags similarly). The culprit is `z-index:1` found in the `:before` rule.

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate some of the additional information from these comments.

Comment: Hey thanks for the video link

Comment: We are currently updating the base CSS of all four of these sites. Once we've finished with the updates. These issues should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you!   I see this is fixed on webmasters already.

Comment: This is apparently still happening at Web Apps: [Phantom triangles on downvote warning](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3760/354)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have caught my attention on this one.  A fix has been pushed and will build out soon.  I also want you to know that our design team has been hard at work at converting all of our .less files to a consistent and uniform layout which will solve most of these issues in the future.  Thanks for the report and we'll keep you posted on the status of the conversion.

Comment: Thanks.   It looks like this has the z-index rules have been removed from all the tag CSS now.

Comment: It is still an issue on the three meta sites where you fixed it.   Can you make do the same fix for the meta sites?

Comment: Looks like this has been "fixed" (at least on meta.gamedev) by adding a `z-index: 2 !important` style to the notification box, but the underlying bug (unnecessary z-indexes on the tags) is still there.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the `z-index:1;` in the rule that causes tags to look tag shaped.  In the case of the gaming site it is `z-index:2;`.

```
.post-tag:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 6px 10px 0px;
    border-color: transparent #DEEFF6;
    left: -6px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Here is a script I wrote to determine which StackExchange sites have this problem:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -e stacksites.html ]
then
    curl -s http://stackexchange.com/sites > stacksites.html
fi   

sites=`grep noscript-link stacksites.html | sed -r 's|.*http\:\/\/||g;s/\.stackexchange.*//g;s/\.(com|net).*//g' | grep -v '\.'`

for site in $sites
do
    if [ ! -e $site.css ]
    then
        curl -s http://cdn.sstatic.net/$site/all.css > $site.css
        sleep 1
    fi
    beforetag=`grep -oE '\.post-tag\:before\{[^\}]+\}' $site.css`
    if echo "$beforetag" | grep -q 'z-index'
    then
        echo $site
    fi  
    if [ ! -e ${site}meta.css ]
    then
        curl -s http://cdn.sstatic.net/${site}meta/all.css > ${site}meta.css
        sleep 1
    fi
    beforetag=`grep -oE '\.post-tag\:before\{[^\}]+\}' ${site}meta.css`
    if echo "$beforetag" | grep -q 'z-index'
    then
        echo ${site}meta
    fi
done
```

It appears that only a few sites have this z-index rule in conjunction with tags:

- webapps
- webappsmeta
- gaming
- gamingmeta
- webmasters
- webmastersmeta
- gamedev
- gamedevmeta

The solution to this problem appears to be to simply remove the z-index CSS rule from this location.   I commented it out using Firebug on the Webmasters site and it did not change how the page is displayed other than fixing this issue.