# Tag appearance bug

Tags: bug, design

When I press the downvote button and when the message pops up, it should overlas the tag(s). But in Arqade, some parts of the tag sticks out from the blue pop up and making it a bit ugly. I don't know if it occurs on other sites, but in Arqade there's this bug. (Please see the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IO1BHb2ssE&feature=youtu.be).)

Comment: Good find. Close the question?

Comment: I already voted, add your vote if you can, but don't delete. I added a reference to your report in the other one. :)